# Excited states and level matching of bosonic closed strings

Tags: string-theory, quantum-states

I am following [Tongs Notes on String Theory](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string.html) and I'm confused about the level 2 excited closed strings. If I got this correct, level 2 excitation state means, that
\begin{align}
N := \sum_i\sum_{n>0} \alpha^i_{-n}\alpha^i_n =2= \sum_i\sum_{n>0} \tilde{\alpha}^i_{-n}\tilde{\alpha}^i_n =: \tilde{N}
\end{align}
where the condition that $N=\tilde{N}$ is refered to as level matching constraint. For the first excited states $\alpha^i_{-1}\tilde{\alpha}^j_{-1}\left|0\right>$ I see that this is fulfilled, since
\begin{align}
N\alpha^i_{-1}\tilde{\alpha}^j_{-1}\left|0\right> = \alpha^i_{-1}\alpha^i_1\alpha^i_{-1}\tilde{\alpha}^j_{-1}\left|0\right>
=\alpha^i_{-1}\tilde{\alpha}^j_{-1}\left|0\right>
\end{align}
and exactly the same for $\tilde{N}$ so we have $N=\tilde{N}=1$. On page 45 however, he states that for example the state $\alpha^i_{-2}\tilde{\alpha}^j_{-2}\left|0\right>$ is a level 2 state, but if I calculate $N$ I find
\begin{align}
N\alpha^i_{-2}\tilde{\alpha}^j_{-2}\left|0\right> = \alpha^i_{-2}\alpha_2^i\alpha^i_{-2}\tilde{\alpha}^j_{-2}\left|0\right> = \alpha^i_{-2}\tilde{\alpha}^j_{-2}\left|0\right>
\end{align}
and therefore $N=1$. So why is this state considered as a level 2 state? I have a similar problem with the level 2 state $\alpha^i_{-1}\alpha^j_{-1}\tilde{\alpha}^k_{-2}\left|0\right>$ he mentions on the same page. Here I find $N=2$ and $\tilde{N}=1$, so this state doesn't even fulfill the level matching constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just forgot the factor of $m$ sitting in the commutation relation
\begin{equation}
[ \alpha^i_m , \alpha^j_n ] = m \delta^{ij} \delta_{m,-n}.
\end{equation}
Taking it into account, you find that
\begin{equation}
N \alpha^i_{-2} \tilde{\alpha}^j_{-2} \left| 0 \right\rangle = \alpha^k_{-2} \alpha^k_2 \alpha^i_{-2} \tilde{\alpha}^j_{-2} \left| 0 \right\rangle = \alpha^k_{-2} \big[\alpha^k_2 , \alpha^i_{-2}\big] \tilde{\alpha}^j_{-2} \left| 0 \right\rangle = \alpha^k_{-2} \big( 2 \delta^{ki} \big)  \tilde{\alpha}^j_{-2} \left| 0 \right\rangle = 2 \alpha^i_{-2} \tilde{\alpha}^j_{-2} \left| 0 \right\rangle.
\end{equation}